# Javascript Equivalent of Element in element

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

What would be the Javascript equivalent of

```
imgsrc = $("#content div form img").attr('src');
```

The HTML is

```
<div id='content'>
    <div>
        <form name='input_form'>
            <img src='image.jpg'>
            <input type='text' value='' name='yourname'>
            <input type='submit' value='Go!'>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've found I can't use Jquery in my current project, So i'm changing everything back to javascript.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

sorry...about the confusing title

Comment: It is already jquery. Perhaps you are asking javascript equivalent?

Comment: Yaaa, sorry guys! Meant javascript.

Comment: jQuery *is* JavaScript. Why can you not use jQuery? The answer is that in *modern* browsers you can use `querySelector()`. If you need to support older browsers, you can't.

Comment: I know that jquery is javascript. I can't use the plugin Jquery on this project.

Comment: @AlanBowen right; well my question is then, why not? Where do such restrictions come from?

Comment: (Be less specific) `document.getElementById("content").getElementsByTagName("img")[0].src`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `querySelector()` method:

```
var imgsrc = document.querySelector("#content div form img")
                     .getAttribute('src'); // => `src` attribute's value 
                     // .src => `src` property
```

http://caniuse.com/queryselector

Comment: ... or just `.src` - no need to use `.getAttribute()`.

Comment: "Older browsers" is a euphemism for IE8.

Comment: Does it select only one img element?

Comment: You're kidding!? Then I may have to consider dropping jQuery. I still like it for doing ajax.

Comment: @antindexer, in the example HTML for the question, there's only one img element, so it can only select one element. Also, queryselector returns the 1st matching element, while querySelectorAll returns a list

Comment: @antindexer Yes, if you want to select all the image elements `querySelectorAll` method should be used.

Comment: `.getAttribute('src')` would get what's in the `src` attribute exactly. `.src` would return a full link to the image.

Answer (score 0):

Untested but this should work

```
document.getElementById('content').getElementsByTagName('div')[0].getElementsByTagName('form')[0].getElementsByTagName('form')[0].getAttribute('src');
```